# Filtering Down Data, then Adding Brackets

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Currently working with a data set about billionaires (small summary included below); I am looking to get them into three age brackets: "40 and under", "41 to 65", and "above 65", then what is the most common category (their kind of profession) of billionaire in each of the three age brackets.

I have tried to select the data down, and mutate or separate to create the brackets, but unsure what to do. The struck out lines are examples of things I have been trying.

```
load("bil.RData")
print(bil)

# A tibble: 2,614 x 22
     age category citizenship company.name company.type country_code founded
   <int> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <chr>        <chr>          <int>
 1    NA Financi… Saudi Arab… Rolaco Trad… new          SAU             1968
 2    34 Financi… United Sta… Fidelity In… new          USA             1946
 3    59 Non-Tra… Brazil      Companhia B… new          BRA             1948
 4    61 New Sec… Germany     Ratiopharm   new          DEU             1881
 5    NA Financi… Hong Kong   Swire        new          HKG             1816
 6    NA Traded … Bahrain     YBA Kanoo    new          BHR             1890
 7    NA New Sec… Japan       Otsuka Hold… new          JPN             1921
 8    NA Traded … Japan       Sony         new          JPN             1946
 9    66 Financi… Japan       Mori Buildi… new          JPN             1959
10    NA Traded … France      Chanel       new          FRA             1909
# … with 2,604 more rows, and 15 more variables: `from emerging` <chr>,
#   gdp <dbl>, gender <chr>, industry <chr>, inherited <chr>, name <chr>,
#   rank <int>, region <chr>, relationship <chr>, sector <chr>, `was
#   founder` <chr>, `was political` <chr>, wealth.type <chr>,
#   worth_billions <dbl>, year <int>
```

```
bil %>% 
    select(age, category) %>%
    arrange(age) %>%
    filter(!is.na(age), !is.na(category)) %>%
    group_by(age, category) %>%
    #mutate(n = sum(age)) %>%
    #separate(col =  age, c("Under 40", "41-65", "Above 65")) %>%
    print()
```

```
# A tibble: 2,158 x 2
# Groups:   age, category [312]
     age category          
   <int> <chr>             
 1    12 Financial         
 2    21 Financial         
 3    24 Financial         
 4    24 Financial         
 5    28 Non-Traded Sectors
 6    28 Resource Related  
 7    29 Financial         
 8    29 Traded Sectors    
 9    29 New Sectors       
10    29 New Sectors
```

Preferably, I am looking for a table with three rows (one per category, under 40, 41-65, 65+), and three columns (age_bracket, most common category, and n). Also, let me know the best way to include data sets on stackoverflow because this set is a bit large for dput() to be useful (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To divide data into different buckets, use `findInterval` or `cut` and then use `top_n` to return top `category` in each bucket.

```
library(dplyr)
bil %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  group_by(group = findInterval(age, c(40, 65))) %>%
  count(category) %>%
  top_n(1, n)
```

This would just return 1, 2, 3 as labels, if you want to name the labels you can do

```
bil %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  group_by(group = c("40 and under", "41 to 65", "above 65")[
                   findInterval(age, c(40, 65)) + 1]) %>%
  count(category) %>%
  top_n(1, n)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response; what does the +1 do in the findInterval line? A bit confused about that functionality.

Comment: @PageSim `findInterval` would return 0 for values less than 40 and in R indexing starts at 1, so we add `+1` to make 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2 etc and use this index to subset values from `c("40 and under", "41 to 65", "above 65")`.

Comment: @PageSim I guess you also need to `count` first and then use `top_n`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be many ways to get what want.

Here are an example of using `table1` :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(table1)

bil1<-bil %>%
  mutate(age_group = cut(hp, 
      breaks = c(0, 40, 65, 110), 
      labels = c("< 40", "40 - 64", "65+")))
table1(~ category) | age_group, data = bil1)
```

You may also want to try many other packages such as `arsenal` and `stargazer`

[image]